# Django User Authentication and Login with DRY

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am trying to create a simple login using Django authentication. All the code here is working but I am thinking that it is violating DRY principles. I will explain:

In my **forms.py** I have a simple login form:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
  email = forms.CharField()
  password = forms.PasswordField()

  def clean(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email', None)
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password', None)
    u = authenticate(email, password)
    if u is None:
      raise forms.ValidationError(ERROR_MSG)
      if not u.is_active:
        raise forms.ValidationError(ERROR_MSG)
```

so I am doing a check of **User** here already. However, in my **views.py**:

```
def login(request):
  login_form = LoginForm(request or None)
  if login_form.is_valid():
    #This part is repeated
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    u = authenticate(email, password)
    login(request, u)

  return render(request, 'home.html', {})
```

I am querying the database again, which to me seems to violate DRY. Does anybody have a better way of doing this? I want to reuse the **LoginForm** for other uses, but also want to do it cleanly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing the `authenticate()` twice, you can set the `user` on the `form` object and then use this `user` in your view.

**forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.PasswordField()

    def clean(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email', None)
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password', None)
        self.u = authenticate(email, password) # set the user as an instance variable
        if self.u is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError(ERROR_MSG)
        if not self.u.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError(ERROR_MSG)
```

**views.py**

```
def login(request):
    login_form = LoginForm(request or None)
    if login_form.is_valid():
        login(request, login_form.u) # directly pass the user by accessing from login_form object

    return render(request, 'home.html', {})
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Rahul! I just have a question about Python in general, when you `raise` an exception, does Python stop execution of all lines of code after the `raise`? I am asking this because I realized that you did not put the second `if` block nested within the first.

Comment: If you have a `raise` statement, in your code, Python will stop execution of all lines of code after it (provided  you don't catch that exception using `try-except`). In case of Django form validation, they have added a `try-except` whenever calling the `clean()` functions of the form. So if there is any `ValidationError`, it will catch that exception and add it to `form.errors` dictionary.

Comment: Inside the `clean` function, if the 1st validation error is raised, then code below it won't be executed i.e. this line `if not self.u.is_active:` won't be executed. But outside this function, Django forms have added `try-except` whenever calling `clean` so then this exception would be caught and the code in the `except` block will be executed. The `except` block then adds the validation error to `form.errors` dictionary.

Comment: Hello Rahul! Thank you for your answer. It seems like there is something about python that allows you to use stuff like self, obj, class etc and put it as parameters. Is there a full topic on this?

Comment: @bryansis2010 You can check out the official Python docs on [classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). Its quite helpful!